# can't get the Element of JSON Object

Tags: java, json, spring, javabeans

I have a jsonobject that contains some json objects

```html
  "paths": {
    "/api/{version}/RAW/getrawdata": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "RAw"
        ],
        "summary": "/getrawdata",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "token",
            "in": "header",
            "description": "gettoken",
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            },
    "/api/{version}/filtered/getfinaldatadata": {
    "get": {
        "tags": [
          "filtered"
        ],
        "summary": "/getfinaldatadata",
```

Now I want to get the elements summary and tags  and want to return the values. Its easy to get the value of summary but tags has [] so I don't know how to take the value e.g RAW .
I was trying something like this

```html
package beans;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Header;
public class URIpattern {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public String URI(JSONObject json,
            @Header (Exchange.SLIP_ENDPOINT) String previous) {
        if(previous!=null){
             return null;


  JSONObject paths= json.getJSONObject("paths");
  JSONObject summary = operation.getString("summary");
    JSONObject tags = operation.getJSONObject("tags");
      return tags + summary;
```

but it is not doing any thing. Can someone please guide me since I am new to java.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is not a valid Json, validate it one more time.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess you are using this [Object](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.M4/api//org/springframework/boot/configurationprocessor/json/JSONObject.html) and inside the defined class you have the function [getJSONArray](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.M4/api//org/springframework/boot/configurationprocessor/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray-java.lang.String-)  after that just use the new ArrayObject and pull the data what you need out of it.

Answer (score -1):

In JSON values are present in [] are treated as arrays. So if you need to extract the `tags`, you will need to get them in a array like,

```
 String json = "{\"tags\":[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"]}";
 JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
 JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("tags");
 System.out.println(array);
```

P.S. I could not find the json posted in question to be valid, hence I have used some exmaple to explain the JSONArray.

Comment: so  if I have twenty tags inside then do i need to add \6,\7....\20?

Comment: You add the values in array separated by comma. And if you want to get the values then
they will be like an arraylist. if you want the first element, you get it using ``array.get(0)``. Similarly  for 20th, you will use ``array.get(19)``

Comment: I mean I need all values of tags. all 20 values

Comment: ``array`` has all the values in it. If you want all values in string separated by comma (any other separator) like ``1,2,3,4,5,6..``. You can use ``join`` function like ``array.join(",")``